# "Connection to remote host was lost." error

Tags: python, websocket

i am trying to make a little program with websocket, but after like 30min of running, i get this big error
`websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.`

(full error : https://paste.pythondiscord.com/oduwigunim)

can someone help me to fix that ?

(the whole code :https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ifabolehit)

Comment: Looks like a network problem...